# Getting an error while storing embedding in ChromaDB

Tags: openai-api, azure-openai, chromadb, vector-database, openaiembeddings

ValueError: Expected EmbeddingFunction.**call** to have the following signature: odict_keys(['self', 'input']), got odict_keys(['self', 'texts'])

Please see https://docs.trychroma.com/embeddings for details of the EmbeddingFunction interface.
Please note the recent change to the EmbeddingFunction interface: https://docs.trychroma.com/migration#migration-to-0416---november-7-2023

This is happening after the Nov 23 Update.